# Java: Linked list node questions

Tags: java, linked-list

I am learning Linked Lists and came across the following code

```
public void add(WordMeaning wm)
{

    WordMeaningNode data = new WordMeaningNode(wm);

    if (head == null)
        head = data;

    else
    {
        WordMeaningNode current = head, prev = null;
        boolean found = false;

        while (current != null && !found)
        {
            if (data.getWordMeaning().getWord().compareTo(current.getWordMeaning().getWord()) < 0)
                found = true;

            else
            {
                prev = current;
                current = current.next;         
            }

        }

        data.next = current;

        if (prev == null)
            head = data;

        else
            prev.next = data;


    }

}
```

This code is used to take a word and definition and then sorts the word alphabetically with the other values in the LinkedList. I understand how to store words in a LinkedList without being sorted alphabetically but I'm having trouble understanding the last part starting with the data.next = current and the if statement that follows. Specifically how data.next and current can be equal to each other as they should both be null. I also don't understand why prev.next in the last else statement cannot be substituted for current as they should be the same value based on the previous else statement in the while loop.

Comment: _"I'm having trouble understanding ... how data.next and current can be equal to each other "_ -- Your question is unclear...  the statement `data.next = current` is an _assignment_ that copies the value of `current` into `data.next`.  After that statement, `data.next` will refer to the same object that `current` refers to.  What is it you don't understand?

Comment: Once a matching position found in the while loop you have to link data node with the current node (found from the while loop) and previous node. If the list is empty then the element is added at the head. This is happening. [check this](http://www.algolist.net/Data_structures/Singly-linked_list/Traversal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that they are not equal. You forget that in the code `data.next = current;`, it is not asserting that the two are equal. It is setting `data.next` to be `current`.

If it still doesn't make sense, think about it this way:

Node `prev` is linked to Node `current` because `prev.next == current` :

```
  prev
prev.next ------> current
                current.next
```

However, we want to insert `data` inbetween the two. Here's what the list should look like afterwards:

```
  prev
prev.next ------> data
                data.next ------> current
                                current.next
```

Therefore, two things need to happen:

- `prev.next` needs to be set to `data`. (We want to change the link and not the thing it links to, so we have to write `prev.next`, not `current`.)
- `data.next` needs to be set to `current`. You are also correct that current *could* be null, but this does not matter since we are allowed to set things to null.

It's more concerning if `prev` is null, since you cannot access `prev.next` if prev does not exist. That's why this is checked for separately.

Answer (score 2):

This code inserts word into linked list so that words in resulting linked list are in ascending order. `data` is new node having a word; the `if` condition inside `while` loop is checking whether word in `current` node is greater than word in `data` node. If so set `found` to true else assign `current` node to previous and `current`'s next node to `current` node. This process repeats until the condition in `while` evaluates to false.

There are two cases here:

1. Once the word in `current`  node is greater than word in `data` node `found` becomes true. Now we know that word in `current` node is alphabetically greater than word in `data` node; so make `current` node as next node of `data` node. this is exactly what `data.next = current;` is doing. We also know that word in `data` node is alphabetically greater than word in `prev` node so make `data` node as next node of `prev` node. This is exactly what `prev.next = data;` of `else` is doing.
2. This case is when list is empty. The `if (prev == null) head = data;` makes `data` node as `head` node when list is empty.